# Java: ActionListener error

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

I have this code that uses a textfield from which the program is to receive input from the user so I'm trying to add an ActionListener to my textfield input. However, when I compile I get this error: 
`Quiz.java:5: error: Quiz is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class Quiz implements ActionListener {`

**Code**:

```
public class Quiz implements ActionListener {

private static Label lblInput;         
private static TextField tfInput;  
private static String cityIn;       

   public void europe() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();      
      frame.setLayout(null);

      lblInput = new Label("Skriv in huvudstaden i : "); // Construct Label
      lblInput.setBounds(40,30,300,40);
      frame.add(lblInput);

      tfInput = new TextField(10);
      tfInput.setBounds(40,70,300,40);
      frame.add(tfInput);

      tfInput.addActionListener(this);

      frame.setTitle("Europa"); 
      frame.setSize(375, 150);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method :

```
public class Quiz implements ActionListener {

    private static Label lblInput;
    private static TextField tfInput;
    private static String cityIn;

    public void europe() {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** *(Second way)*

You can handle events on your textfield using a custom `ActionListener`:

```
public class Quiz implements ActionListener {

    private static Label lblInput;
    private static TextField tfInput;
    private static String cityIn;

    public void europe() {
        ....
        tfInput.addActionListener(new CustomActionListener());
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Your code
    }
}

class CustomActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Your code
    }
}
```